# Why this Jquery code does not run?

Tags: jquery

I have Jquery code that checks on .change status of HTML select element and when there's change in select element it should check if certain radio button is active.

```
 $('#select_ele').change(function(){
     //
     //... Doing all kind of fancy stuff here
     //
     if($('input[name="radio_button"]').val() == 'bp'){
         alert('YO'); 
     }
 });
```

So the idea here was on change of select check if 'bp' radio button is active and if so then alert me.

Comment: Are you wrapping up your code in the $(document).ready event? (Or the shorthand $(function() { ... });)

Comment: yeah im all wrapped up in correct stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will always give you the `.val()` of the first `name="radio_button"` match it finds, whether or not it is checked.

Instead, you should use the [`checked-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)  to get the one that is checked.

```
$('input[name="radio_button"]:checked').val() == 'bp'
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quite silly of me since i have been using that :checked selector in other parts of my document :(

Answer (score 2):

Your code is probably running before the document loads.
Therefore, the selector isn't matching anything (since the document hasn't been parsed yet), and the script doesn't do anything
Move the `<script>` block to the bottom of the page or wrap it in `$(function() { ... })` (this executes it in the document load event).

Comment: doh ofc i got this :) Anyways if i wouldn't have firebug would throw me errors.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you're looking for:

if($('input[name="bp"]').is(":checked"){
        alert("yo");
    })

Comment: it's the value = bp not name. I got name thats shared across 5 radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Please this in the middle, it will help you work it out.

```
alert("Hello I am Working")
```

As well as this.

```
console.log(event.type);
```